# How to queue upload to s3 using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I'm dispatching a job to queue my video file, the files are being stored on s3.
Everything is working except if I upload a video file for example that's 20mb, when I look in my bucket it says the file is 120b. So this makes me think that I'm uploading the path and filename as a string instead of the file object.
And for some reason, when I try getting the file using the `Storage::get()` or `File::get()` and dd the result, it shows a bunch or random and crazy characters.
It seems like I can only get these weird characters, or a string, I can't get the file object for some reason.

In my controller I'm also storing it in the public disk (I will delete the file later in my Jobs/UploadVideos.php file).

CandidateProfileController.php:

```
$candidateProfile = new CandidateProfile();
$candidateProfile->disk = config('site.upload_disk');

// Video One
if($file = $request->file('video_one')) {
    $file_path = $file->getPathname();
    $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

    $file->storePubliclyAs('videos', $name, 'public');
    $candidateProfile->video_one = $name;
}

if($candidateProfile->save()) {

    // dispatch a job to handle the image manipulation
    $this->dispatch(new UploadVideos($candidateProfile));

    return response()->json($candidateProfile, 200);

} else {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Some error occurred, please try again.',
        'status' => 500
    ], 500);
}
```

Jobs/UploadVideos.php:

```
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $candidateprofile;
    public $timeout = 120;
    public $tries = 5;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param CandidateProfile $candidateProfile
     */
    public function __construct(CandidateProfile $candidateProfile)
    {
        $this->candidateprofile = $candidateProfile;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $disk = $this->candidateprofile->disk;
        $filename = $this->candidateprofile->video_one;
        $original_file = storage_path() . '/videos/' . $filename;

        try {
            // Video One
            Storage::disk($disk)
                ->put('videos/'.$filename, $original_file, 'public');

            // Update the database record with successful flag
            $this->candidateprofile->update([
                'upload_successful' => true
            ]);

        } catch(\Exception $e){
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to confirm, is you Job meant to be **copying** the file from your `public` disk to S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[File Storage docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#storing-files)

The 2nd parameter for `put()` should be the contents of the file not the path to the file. Also, unless you've updated the `public` disk in your `config/filesystem.php`, the video isn't going to be stored in `storage_path() . '/videos/...'`.

To get this to work you should just need to update your `Job` code:

```
$filename = 'videos/' . $this->candidateprofile->video_one;

Storage::disk($this->candidateprofile->disk)
    ->put($filename, Storage::disk('public')->get($filename), 'public');

$this->candidateprofile->update([
    'upload_successful' => true,
]);
```

Also, wrapping your code in a `try/catch` will mean that the Job won't retry as it will technically never fail.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the try/catch, now I have ```public $tries = 5;``` so it should retry 5 times. Is this setting okay or should I just leave it so it keeps trying and trying in the background?

Comment: @RyanSacks 5 retires should be more than fine. TBF, I would be tempted to lower it to something like 3 but it's completely up to you. :)